# Using my own dataset for classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I am building a ANN module to conduct classification in python. The demo I get imports ClassificationDataSet module

```
    from pybrain.datasets import ClassificationDataSet
    alldata = ClassificationDataSet(2, 1, nb_classes=3)
```

and I am wondering how can I use my own data. My data is list type. Is there any processing I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

The ClassificationDataSet returns a class, where you can pass your own data there.

It is explained in [the documentation](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/blob/master/docs/documentation.pdf) (search through their github repo in case the link does not work) in section 2.2 (2.2.2 for a custom  dataset and 2.2.3 for how to add samples to it).

Comment: you should improve your answer by inserting the specific parts in the documentation. also, some links might not work in the future, hence, it's really important to post the relevant information.

Comment: Thanks, I think I figured out that I need to add samples to the class. Can I continue asking that why the nb_classes =3? Or how to set this value? FYI, I am trying to build a module with 20 input and 1 output.